# How pass compiler flags to ExternalProject_Add to build gtest for x32

Tags: cmake, googletest

I have following part of cmake:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(gtest
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git 
    GIT_TAG release-1.12.1   
  
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
)
```

Somewhere earlier in cmake I have:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -m32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -m32)
```

How to pass these flags to build googletest for x32 architecture?

Comment: Is there a proof of googletest being built for x64?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
ExternalProject_Add(gtest
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest.git 
    GIT_TAG release-1.12.1   
  
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest
    CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
)
```